# How to redirect to callback url using POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie to ASP.NET NVC and I'm currently (self) learning how to consume Web APIs. I want to integrate an OAuth Web API into my ASP.NET MVC application to have the following flow.

1. User clicks Login Button
2. redirect to API-login website
3. User logs in
4. User accepts T&C
5. The redirected page URL has the access token
6. Access token is retrieved by the main MVC app
7. Using HTTP Post, the necessary data is displayed on the page.

Currently I am able to redirect to the login website using the `Redirect(Uri url)` method and carry out steps 1-4. However, I am stuck at step 5 where the T&C page redirects to a page with the access token as part of the URL, which produces a server error (because I haven't implemented the `https://localhost:5241/redirect` in my application yet)

The URL with the token is in the form `https://localhost:5241/redirect?token="abcde..."`

Please advise me as to how I should implement the `/redirect` portion to redirect to my main page (in step 1), and how I can parse the token from the redirected URL.

My current approach is to create a redirect controller which redirects to the main page (home controller) and creates the POST request in step 7.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).